# Can I define a member function in a seperate source file to the class source file?

Tags: c++, performance, member-functions

I have a source for a class in C++ that has many member functions. I am trying to decide whether or not to put a portion of the member function definitions in another source.

If I do, is this likely to drastically effect compilation and/or execution of the program?

Comment: I would not post this as an answer but you should consider to split up your class into multiple classes. Google for single responsibility principle (SRP).

Comment: I have considered this too, and tried to think through how that would best work, and it feels to me like that wouldn't make sense in this scenario. I could well be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the implementations in whatever file you want. Once the sources are compiled, it doesn't matter where the methods were implemented. It may have some effect on the compilation time, but unless you're doing something extreme, like having thousands of member functions, each one in a different file, this effect should be negligible.

Comment: So will the executable be effected? Or will the compiler just organise the extra file of functions as a continuation of the original file as if it were in the same function?

Comment: @IronAttorney If you end up **linking** all the resulting object files together, it won't matter what source file they were originally in. I.e., the executable shouldn't be affected.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, I might give this a whirl then. Just as a side note, I'm using the codeblocks IDE (I know that's frowned upon round here, but what you gonna do? :D ), and I am therefore in the dark about the linking stage. I can only assume codeblocks will do this satisfactory for me ;)

Comment: Yes, if you're able to run your program, then it has been linked properly. Compilers usually do this after the compilation step.

Comment: It can make a difference as far as inlining.

Comment: Aha, inlining is something else I know very little about. When I think I'm starting to get a handle on it, I always find out there is much more to know! I should read up on that before making my decision then.

Comment: Ok, so I have two slightly conflicting answers... slightly. Mureinik suggests that the executable will be the same, whereas @Vaughn Cato 's answer leaves open the possibility for it being effected dependant on the compiler and linker. Any further thoughts from anyone on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is unusual, but if you have your class definition in a header file, then you can have multiple source files for the member function definitions.  Each source file will include the common header file.  For example:

```
// foo.hpp
struct Foo {
    void f();
    void g();
};
```

---

```
// foo_f.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"

void Foo::f()
{
   .
   .
   .
}
```

---

```
// foo_g.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"

void Foo::g()
{
   .
   .
   .
}
```

As far as affecting compile times, it depends.  You could see an improvement in incremental compilation.  For example, you wouldn't have to recompile foo_g.cpp if you only made a change to foo_f.cpp.  However, if you changed foo.hpp, then both foo_f.cpp and foo_g.cpp would need to be recompiled.

As far as affecting execution time, it depends.  Some compilers may do more optimization if the member functions are all in the same source file.   For example, if `f()` calls `g()`, the compiler may be able to inline `g()` into `f()` if `g()` is defined in the same source file.  Some compilers may not do this optimization, but some linkers may be able to do this optimization even if `f()` and `g()` are in different files.

Comment: You'll just need to link the extra .o required for your class.

Comment: But what of the compilation and execution?

Comment: @IronAttorney: I've extended my answer to address compilation and execution times.

Comment: Ok, so really I need to set up a test program using my own envirenment and do some benchmarks. I don't know much about inlining, but I think you're extra answer there may have given away some key aspects of what it is. Thank you very much!

Comment: Would it be uncouth to untick the other answer and tick this one? This one is now more complete than the first.